# get scroll bar to attach to correct div

Tags: html, css

I have a "pop-up" table which is a fixed element. The table is sometimes to high to fit on some screens so I have set `overflow` to `auto`. However the scrollbar appears detached from the pop-up table as it is only 80% the width of the entire "blanket"(which covers the screen). Is there a way to get the scroll bar to attach directly right of the pop-up table without the gap? here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ssjkgb22/) to show you what I mean. Thank you.

**html**

```
<div id = "blanket">
  <div>
    <table align = "center" id = "popUpTable">
      <tr>
        <td>fixed pop uptable</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>one</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>    
        <td>three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>    
        <td>four</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>    
</div>

<div>background stuff<br>background stuff<br>background stuff<br></div>
```

**css**

```
#blanket{
      position:fixed;
      top:0%;
      bottom:0%;
      left:0%;
      right:0%;
      background-color:rgba(255,555,255,0.5); 
      overflow-y:auto;
}

#popUpTable{
         border:1px solid gray;
         margin-top:2%;
         width:80%;
         background-color:#fff;

}

#popUpTable td{
            height:150px;
            text-align:center;
            border:1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: what is the desired height for table then?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following seems to do the trick....

```
#blanket {
    width:80%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-40%;
}

#popUpTable{
    width:100%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2dx5hjn/

Comment: then the pop-up table is not centered in the screen

Comment: @user2014429 Ok. I didn't realise that was a requirement. I'll see what options there are.

Comment: @user2014429 how about giving `#blanket{width:80%}` also?